# Sending string value in google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, web-analytics

I am trying to bind events for events tracking by Google Analytics.
While making a call to GA, we can send some value also.

I am trying to send value by DOM selector.

When I use:

```
myValue=function(){return parseInt($('.checkout-order-totals .order-total  td:last').text().replace('$','').replace(/,/g,'')).valueOf(); }
```

It works perfectly fine (showing click event in omnibug).

But when I remove parseInt from the above code,
i.e,

```
myValue=function(){return $('.checkout-order-totals .order-total  td:last').text().replace('$','').replace(/,/g,'').valueOf(); }
```

it does not send request to GA. (not showing click event in omnibug)

What can be the possible reasons for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [GA documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#overview), the `Value`parameter must be a JS Number.

Therefore, it is not surprising that the request is not sent, as it must fail some validation.